# Limited output: PLM R

Tags: r, plm

I am trying to run a regression in R, using the plm package, on a unbalanced, relatively large data set (111738x66). However, in the output I get, only the coefficients are displayed, but the std errors, p values, etc, are not.

Further, there are 21 variables in the regression.

This is essentially the code that I am using

```
year1logyearC <- plm(formula = eddata.lfsato ~  eddata.sex + eddata.agesq + eddata.wav1 + eddata.wav2 + eddata.wav3 + eddata.wav4 + eddata.wav5 + eddata.wav6 + eddata.wav7 + eddata.wav8 + eddata.wav9 + eddata.wav10 + eddata.wav11 + eddata.wav12 + eddata.wav13 + eddata.wav14 + eddata.wav15 + eddata.wav16 + eddata.wav17  + eddata.eth1 + eddata.eth2 + cycle + eddata.logfiyr + cycle:eddata.logfiyr  ,  method =“pooling”, data = PMCombFinNewRef1)
```

Might there be a way to get the data displayed?

Further, if to the output of this, I use the following commands

```
kable(tidy(year1logyearC), digits=5, 
  caption="Pooled model")
```

I get a nice table with most of the things I need (apart from DF and other stuff)... 
Any reasons why that might be the case?

I think it is more to do with something like preferences or other setting perhaps?

I know - that I should add a reproducible example, but it is really difficult, because not only is the data sensitive, but also because there are 200 lines of code before. (Yes, I have tested those 200 lines and they work just fine! Ran a bunch of regressions using lm... and I have the complete output using lm)

Comment: Using 'summary' I am able to get the results I need. Thanks

Comment: Do you mind posting that as an answer and accept you answer so this question does not stay unanswered in SO?

Answer (score 0):

Using 'summary' I am able to get the results I need

Thus,

```
summary(year1logyearC)
```